# aes_encrypt doesn't exist in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to encrypt some columns in Hive tables. Normally I used for that aes_encrypt UDF function in Hive. However, seems like it doesn't exists in Spark. 
Is there any existing alternative in Spark or I just need to write my own UDF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an old ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12567

However, it's not under active development. You can ping on Jira and/or ask someone of the community if they can help you.

Now, you have to write your own UDF.

You may also be interested in using Hive UDFs in Spark, then you have to use session with Hive support. More details here: https://github.com/bmc/spark-hive-udf